# calculate the difference between two binary numbers with a logic circuit

Tags: binary, logic, subtraction, twos-complement, circuit

I wanted design a logic circuit that calculates the difference between two binary numbers with sign A and B with 4 bit and also would like to calculate propagation delay and determine the value??
could anyone help!
 I did make a xor gate with a input of add/sub and B's value to it and connected to full adders where 1 is added to a first full adders when sub value is 1 to make it two's complement.
My problem is with the sign bit. Do I have to change A's value in 2's complement when it is negative(I'm just confused)

Comment: Some background and your attempts to solve it would be helpful. Don't just paste your assignment here.

Answer (score 0):

To acquire the difference between two numbers, A and B, it is necessary to do the 2's complement of either A or B.

Many newbies are confused by the operation of generating 2's complement.

Don't forget that you have to define the scale of the adder, a.k.a, 4bits? 8bits? And the left-most bit is the sign bit.

For example, let's treat `A = 4` and `B = -1`, apparently a 4-bit adder is sufficent.

```
A = 0100 and B = ~(0001) + 1 = 1111
```

in representation of 2's complement.

Because you ask for difference, we should do a 2's complement again for B.

```
A-B = 0100 + ~(1111)+1 = 0101
A-B = 5.
```

As Guffa suggested, you should study some material on wiki before you ask such question.